# função count traz quantidade diferente de acordo aos parâmetros de data passados

Tags: cakephp

Eu preciso pegar o mês e o ano duas vezes: para consultar as despesas e calcular a quantidade de despesas encontradas.

Na `function consultarDespesas`, passo para as duas variáveis globais para posteriormente acessar elas na `function quantidadeDespesas`. O `$this->request->data['Despesa']['ano'] e $this->request->data['Despesa']['mes']` ficam `null`. Não sei como faço para acessar em qualquer parte do *controller* Despesas esta requisição.

Então, preferi pegar o mes e ano logo, mas mesmo assim as duas variáveis globais ficam null quando o programa chega na `function quantidadeDespesas`.

Já *debuguei* as duas variáveis globais ou atributos, já *debuguei* `$this->request->data` e `$this->data`, mas não adianta, tudo fica `null`. Vejamos os códigos:

```
class DespesasController extends AppController {

public $helpers=array('Form', 'Html');

public $ano;
public $mes;

public $uses = array('Despesa', 'Receita');
```

### função para procurar as despesas:

```
public function consultarDespesa() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->ano = $this->data['Despesa']['ano'];
            $this->mes = $this->data['Despesa']['mes'];

            $despesas = $this->Despesa->find('all',
            array(
    'conditions'=>array(
    'YEAR(data_despesa)'=>$this->request->data['Despesa']['ano'],
    'MONTH(data_despesa)'=>$this->request->data['Despesa']['mes'])));

            if ($despesas == null) {
                $this->Session->setFlash("Sua pesquisa não retornou nenhum resultado.");
            }

            else {
                $this->Session->write("Despesas", $despesas);

                $this->quantidadeDespesas();
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'exibirDespesas'));
            } 
    }
}
```

### Função para contar quantas despesas encontradas:

```
public function quantidadeDespesas() {
    $quantidadeDespesas = $this->Despesa->query("select count(id_despesa) as quantidadeDespesas from despesas where year(data_despesa)='$this->ano' and MONTH(data_despesa)='$this->mes'");

    return $quantidadeDespesas;
}
```

Comment: Você já debugou antes do if( $this->request->is( ...?
Verifica se o method do form é post mesmo.

Comment: Você também pode usar o Count do Cake mesmo, basta setar as condições
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count